Need Assistance: Email Configuration for Dynamic 'From' and 'Reply-To' Addresses in Salesforce
In my Salesforce org, I have a requirement where, whenever the status of an inquiry is changed to "Not Reachable," an email should be sent to the inquiry owner. Here's how the email behavior should work:
From Address: The email's "From" address should dynamically reflect the inquiry owner's email address, regardless of which user in the org changes the status.
Reply-To Address: When the inquiry owner replies to the email, the "Reply-To" address should be set to a custom customer care email (e.g., customercare@yourcompany.com).
The Issues I'm Facing:
With Flow: I can change the "From" address of the email, but I cannot find an option to set the "Reply-To" address.
With Apex: I can set the "Reply-To" address, but I'm unable to dynamically change the "From" address to reflect the inquiry owner's email.
what i need:
I’m looking for a solution that satisfies both requirements:
Dynamically set the "From" address to the inquiry owner's email.
Set the "Reply-To" address to the custom customer care email.
What would be the best approach to resolve this?


Welcome to SFSE. Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour].  We cannot implement your requirements or provide complete designs, but we're happy to help you with issues you encounter as you do your own work.  Please [edit] your question to show us what you've tried and where you are stuck.
